# Drupal 7 update field programatically and generate field names

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm here still learning with drupal 7 but now I have a new question about a node create programmatically,I hope you can help me.

I want to generate all node fields names programmatically and then set a lavue on each one.

To store each field from node I generate the names of the field witn an array with each name, this is because I want to make  function to indicate the names of the fields of the node that I want to fill.

The problem is that my code is not working to fill the nodes, maybe because my fields names are bad generated. I generate and fill them this way:

```
    $nodefields = array('areaid', 'areaname');

    foreach ($nodefields as $fieldname) {
            $node->$fieldname['und'][0]['value'] = $row->$fieldname;
            }
    node_save($node);
```

The rows are obtained by a query to a external db (column has the same name as the field), that's fine, the records are ok, if I fill them manually like:

```
$node->areaname['und'][0]['value'] = $row->$areaname;
```

Works ok, but I can't make it work with a loop to generalize that part.

Comment: _maybe because my fields are bad generated_ The code you showed here does not generate any fields. Can you include that code too?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I believe that was my mistake in my question, I mean that, when you want to save a node field value programatically you do somethink like this: $node->areaname['und'][0]['value'] = $row->$areaname; but now, I have an array with the names of the fields, to loop and save the value on each one with this: $node->$field['und'][0]['value'] = $row->$field;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that below code does not work as you probably expect.

```
$node->$fieldname['und'][0]['value'] = $row->$fieldname;
```

You expect this to work like this:

```
$fieldname = 'name'; 
$node->name['und'][0]['value'] = $row->name;
```

but PHP will probably do something like this:

```
$fieldname = 'name'; 
$fieldname['und'][0]['value'] = $row->name;
$node->$row->name;
```

Instead, try to wrap your variable name in curly brackets to have it replaced first:

```
$node->{$fieldname}['und'][0]['value'] = $row->$fieldname;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check it later and as I guess I'll mark your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing brackets

```
$nodefields = array('areaid', 'areaname');
foreach ($nodefields as $fieldname) {
  $node->{$fieldname}['und'][0]['value'] = $row->{$fieldname};
}
node_save($node);
```